# Grab a Html section name using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a basic quiz that matches a drop down menu to the correct value for a block of text.

This is the format of the drop down menu and paragraph:

```
<section class = "drop-menu">
    <select id="drop1">
        <option value='0'>Select True or False:</option>
        <option value='1'>T</option>
        <option value='2'>F</option>
    </select>
</section>

<section class="box1" id = "1" name = "T">
    Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste.
</section>
```

And I'm trying to match the answers using:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick=onSubmitClick();> Submit</button>
```

And this function:

```
function onSubmitClick() {
    var i = document.getElementById("drop1");
    var submOne = i.options[i.selectedIndex].text;

    var w = document.getElementById("1");
    var answrOne = w.name;
    if(submOne === answrOne)
    {
        alert("Correct!");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please Try Again!");
    }
}
```

Right now I'm attempting to grab the section name="T" with `var answrOne = w.name;` but it is always saying "Please Try Again!", how do you properly grab the section name to compare to the submitted answer? Thanks!

Comment: There is no `name` attribute for the `<section>` element. Start by writing HTML.

Comment: What can I use to check the section then?

Comment: id, class, data-*, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
var answrOne = w.name;
```

to

```
var answrOne = w.getAttribute('name');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6mnne/1/)**